# How to identify in jQuery whether an image src is a path or base64 string

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64

I am working with image in jQuery. Actually I have an image tag which sometimes has src with base 64 like these

```
 <img id="profileImage" src="images/blank_photo.png" width="240" height="240"  />
```

Sometimes on the image src there will be an base64 string like these:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD......
```

and sometimes the image src will be the image path

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-f87Bg7JWR4A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABg/sT5evwC9ziw/photo.jpg
```

So the problem is how can I identify in jQuery whether its an base64 or an image path... Is there any method in jQuery by which we can identify or we have to general methods like applying if condition and searching for an substring like http.

Is there any better solution for these.....

Answer (score 1):

You have base64 in src attribute for images.To get objects having src containing base64 :

```
var withbase64img = $("img[src*='base64']");
```

For looping through them:

```
$("img[src*='base64']").each(function(){
    //code here
});
```

Comment: Now let's hope there won't be any image URL like `http://server/path/to/something-base64.jpg`...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: using `$("img[src*='/jpeg;base64']")` in that case should work.

Comment: True, but why not match the `data:` prefix instead? Only data URIs can start with it.